# Entirely clear session for Revel framework

Tags: go, revel

I'm looking for a way to clear a session using the Revel framework. I've tried c.Session["REVEL_SESSION"] = "" and a few other things to reset it but I have not been successful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```golang
delete(c.Session, "REVEL_SESSION")
```